Custom terms of service for Google Workspace users
Assume I have a business Google workspace with several existing users who are all using the standard Google services as part of their work (Gmail, Drive, Calendar, etc.). For legal purposes, I would like each user to agree to specific terms and conditions before accessing any of the Google services. Is this to do?
For example, assume one of my users is attempting to access a Google Site in our workspace. They click on the link to the site and, because it is a private Google Site, they are asked to login. Either on the screen where they enter their Google credentials or right after, I would like to present them with a screen consenting to our terms of access. Is this possible?
